# Remove unnecessary white spacing chart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good morning, I am facing a problem I can not solve. I have a page, and it has two charts, but the problem is that these charts, are small, with lots of white space around them. I've tried setting the Position and InnerPlotPosition property, but worse, it is a white board above the graph.

Today the sources I have are as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <asp:Chart ID="grfStatus" runat="server" PaletteCustomColors="2, 65, 142; 255, 128, 0; Yellow; Red; Lime" Height="400px" Width="600px" BorderlineColor="Transparent">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes="True" AlignmentOrientation="All">
                    <AxisY MaximumAutoSize="100">
                    </AxisY>
                    <AxisX MaximumAutoSize="100">
                    </AxisX>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title Name="Title1" Text="Gráfico de Status" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 18pt" ForeColor="White">
                </asp:Title>
            </Titles>
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Row" />
            </Legends>
            <BorderSkin BackColor="0, 65, 139" BorderColor="Transparent" SkinStyle="FrameTitle8" />
        </asp:Chart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <asp:Chart ID="grfClientes" runat="server" PaletteCustomColors="2, 65, 142; 255, 128, 0; Yellow; Red; Lime" Height="400px" Width="600px">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="StackedBar" IsVisibleInLegend="False"></asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes="True" AlignmentOrientation="All">
                    <AxisY MaximumAutoSize="100">
                    </AxisY>
                    <AxisX MaximumAutoSize="100">
                    </AxisX>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title Name="Title1" Text="Gráfico de Evolução por Empresa" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 18pt" ForeColor="White">
                </asp:Title>
            </Titles>
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Row" />
            </Legends>
            <BorderSkin BackColor="0, 65, 139" SkinStyle="FrameTitle8" />
        </asp:Chart>
    </div>
```

C#

```
#region Populo o gráfico de pizza
        grfStatus.Series.Clear();
        //grfStatus.Legends.Clear();
        //grfStatus.Legends.Add(nomeLegenda);
        List<GraficoContagemStatus> relacaoStatus = visaoAgendamentoControle.ObterRelacaoGraficoContagemStatus(resultado);

        grfStatus.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
        grfStatus.Series.Add(new Series("Data"));
        grfStatus.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        //grfStatus.Series["Data"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
        //grfStatus.Series["Data"]["PieLineColor"] = "Black";
        grfStatus.Series["Data"].Points.DataBindXY(relacaoStatus.Select(data => data.Status.ToString()).ToArray(),
                                                   relacaoStatus.Select(data => data.Contagem).ToArray());
        #endregion

        #region Populo o gráfico de barras (duplas)
        grfClientes.Series.Clear();
        //grfClientes.Legends.Clear();
        //grfClientes.Legends.Add(nomeLegenda);
        List<GraficoContagemClienteUz> relacaoClientes = visaoAgendamentoControle.ObterRelacaoGraficoContagemClienteUz(resultado);

        foreach (GraficoContagemClienteUz cliente in relacaoClientes)
        {
            grfClientes.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
            grfClientes.Series.Add(new Series(cliente.CLIENTE));
            grfClientes.Series[cliente.CLIENTE].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

            List<GraficoContagemClienteUz> rel = relacaoClientes.Where(x => x.CLIENTE == cliente.CLIENTE).ToList();

            grfClientes.Series[cliente.CLIENTE].Points.DataBindXY(rel.Select(data => data.CLIENTE.ToString()).ToArray(),
                                                                  rel.Select(data => data.QTD_UZ).ToArray());

        }
        #endregion
```

And follows the resulting image is today:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgluk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding multiple `ChartArea`s within your loop all over again. You already did it through your markup. Same thing for your `Series`. Use your loop only to add points to your existing series. This is what your chart would look like:

[image]